# Sikuli script does not run on Linux

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

My SikuliX script run on Windows10. However, under Linux (Debian 7.11), the script only opens my application and refuses to continue to execute the remaining script. I tried running on SikuliX versions 1.1.4 and 2.0.1.
Gives an error message:

> “[Error] App.isRunning: '[ps, -p, -1]' Process exited with an error: 1
>   (Exit value: 1)”

Please tell me what is the matter here and is it possible to fix this error?

System Information:

```
Debian OS 7.11

/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java320.so
/opt/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/build/lib/libopencv_java320.so
```

I have java -version installed:

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

Here is my script:

```
uc = App("/opt/UniversalReader/UniversalReader-v3.9.22_x64")
uc.open()
if not uc.isRunning(10): # wait max 10 seconds
    exit(1)
wait(0.3)
mTL = find("Iconuc.png") # find top left.
mBEx = find("PrimerBtn.png")
hover(mBEx.getCenter().click())
while not exists("Listofexamples.png"):
    sleep(5)
click("findTestDatabtn.png")
for x in findAll("Closebtn.png"):
    sleep(1)
click("Closebtn.png")
click("Closebtn.png")
click("Closebtn.png")
mClbtn = find("CloseBtnPanel.png")
click(mClbtn)
while not exists("WinClose.png"):
    sleep(5)
click("NoBtn.png")
mExitBtn = mTL.nearby(1000).right().find("ExitBtn.png") # find top right
click(mExitBtn)
while not exists("WinExit.png"):
    sleep(5)
click("NoBtn.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is RaiMan from SikuliX - sorry for the delay (you already asked on Launchpad).

Apparently the feature App.isRunning() does not work on Linux as expected. So I take it as a bug.

You should wait for your app to be ready in another way.
You might e.g. check visually or by looking for a text on the screen.

Comment: RaiMan, no question. I will be glad to any of your advice! So far, for my part, I'll try to rebuild Java on CMake with the latest OpenCV. Maybe I'll try to take a later Open JDK.